# Formatting text inside PYQT4?

Tags: python, pyqt4

```
userPassword = user_input
password = QtGui.QLabel('{}', self).format(userPassword)
```

I want the label to have the text inside which has been entered by the user? ERROR BELOW

```
AttributeError: 'QLabel' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: try `password = QtGui.QLabel('{}', self)` then `password.setText(userPassword)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the format function is `str.format()`

([Python Docs for str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format))

So your code should be this since you want to format the String(i.e. the '{}') and not the QLabel Object:

```
userPassword = user_input
password = QtGui.QLabel('{}'.format(userPassword), self)
```